# How to manually activate download manager process via adb or terminal emulator?

Tags: adb, terminal

Playstore relies on a process called download manager embedded in Android OS, yet it cannot be manually activate resulting in prolong wait time when using secure proxy to download playstore apps. What would be a good way to manually activate download manager via adb or terminal emulator?

Comment: I'm afraid no..